# Typescript: handle data from service

Tags: javascript, typescript, service

I would like to display users' data, but I have a problem with displaying the correct profile pictures. If a user does not have a profile picture, I get "undefined" in the console. If one user has a profile picture, then the same picture will be displayed for all the users. I need help finding the error in my code.

```
export interface UserData {
 id: number,
 name: string
}

export interface UserWithImage extends UserData{
  image?: string
}

export interface UserProfileImage {
  id: number,
  url: string
}
```

After I get the necessary data from the services, I try to push the profile image into the userData.

user-data.ts

```
userData: UserWithImage[];
userProfiles: UserProfileImage[];
userProfileImage: UserProfileImage[];

getUserData() {
  this.userData = this.userService.getData();
  this.userProfiles = await this.imagesService.getProfilePicture(this.userData?.map(u => u.id));
  this.userProfileImage = this.userProfiles.filter(u => u.url);
  this.userData?.forEach((data, i) => {
    data.image = this.userProfileImage[i].url;
  });
}
```

images.service.ts

```
public async getProfilePicture(ids: number[]): Promise<UserProfileImage[]> {
  const toLoad = ids.filter(id => !this.userProfileImages.find(up => up.id === id)).map(u => u);
  if (toLoad || toLoad.length) {
  const loaded = (await firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.post<UserProfile[]> 
  (this.imgService.getServiceUrl(customersScope, `${basePath}settings/users/profil`), JSON.stringify(toLoad), {headers}))).map(sp => {
    return {
      id: sp.userId,
      url: sp.profilepicId ? this.imgService.getServiceUrl(customersScope, 
      `${basePath}web/download/profilepic/${sp.profilepicId}/users/${sp.userId}`, true) : ''
    } as UserProfileImage
  });
  this.userProfileImages = [...loaded, ...this.userProfileImages];
}
return this.userProfileImages;
}
```

user-data.html

```
<div ngFor="data of userData">
  <etc-profil [name]="data.name" [image]="data.image"></etc-profil>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.userData = this.userService.getData();
```

Is this an async function (i.e. are you missing an `await`)?

```
this.userProfiles = await this.imagesService.getProfilePicture(this.userData?.map(u => u.id));
```

This line would fail is this.userData is a promise.  this.userProfiles would be `undefined` due to the use of optional chaining (`?.`)

```
this.userProfileImage = this.userProfiles.filter(u => u.url);
```

This line appears to do nothing, the filter predicate is saying that anything with a `url` property that is not `null` or `undefined` is included, but the interface says that `url` is non-optional and doesn't support `null` or `undefined`.

```
this.userData?.forEach((data, i) => {
  data.image = this.userProfileImage[i].url;
});
```

Again, if `this.userData` is a promise, this will do nothing due to the optional chaining.

If it does run, its assumed that there is a one-to-one relationship between users and profile images (index count and order must be the same).

I didn't consider the implementation of `getProfilePicture` because I think these issues need resolving first.